# Asking questions relating to the original question

Tags: discussion, behavior

In other words, I had a question regarding a piece of code, a long thread ensued, then a day or so later working on that same piece of code, I had another un/or related question. How do you approach this scenario? The reason I ask is because  this next question had new information (like links and code that I would like to format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a new question ask your new question, ask a new question.

You're more than welcome to mention within the body of the question that you asked an earlier related question and include a link to it.  You do not *need* to link to the old question if you do not want to.

The new question shouldn't be reliant on the old question for information.  If there is information essential to answering it then it should be in the new question.  The old question should merely be there for people interested in additional supplemental information or context.

Answer (score 3):

#### Ask a new question, and link to the old question.

Comment: @Robert: thanks. Formatting accident.